# Adding custom text to each user profile

Tags: users

In D7 i want to let admin add custom text(description) to each user profile and add point to users .
for example the user profile must be like this :

> John
>      Description : You'r not good at speaking
>   point : 12
>
> Joe
>     Description : You'r perfect
>   point : 20

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use [field permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

Add fields for these info & restrict the permissions for them to admin only.

Comment: Thx , this is perfect . one more question : is it possible to have log ? i mean the history of these field that admin put/write for 2 month ago?

Comment: You can take help of https://drupal.org/project/track_field_changes